# Get .src in Javascript from PHP while

Tags: javascript, php, html, while-loop, addeventlistener

I have a folder with a couple of images. I´m using `PHP` to get the path of each image to show them in a `HTML <table>`. Now i´m trying to use the `addEventListener` to show the image in another `div`. I begin to show you my `PHP`:

```
<table id="imgTable">
<tr>
<?php 
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(_FILE_)).'../up/to/my/folder');
while($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
        echo '<tr><img src="../up/to/my/folder/' .$file. '" alt="image" class="imgClass"></td>';
    }
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

After that i want to use the `addEventListener` to get the URL from the clicked image and use the src to display the image in another `div`. Like a photo-gallary.
Thats what I have in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName('img').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById('imgViewer').style.visibility= "visible";
    var img = document.getElemensByClassName('imgClass');
    for(i=0; i<img.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('bigImg')src = img[i].src;
    }
} 
</script>
```

After that, I use to show the image in a with `CSS` hidden `div`:

```
<div id="imgViewer">
    <img src="../up/to/my/folder/imgholder.png" id="bigImg">
</div>
```

I dont want to use `onClick`. But there comes no reaction with `addEventListener` and I don´t understand why. It´s my first year in the University and I had just begun to write JavaScript. Maybe there is somebody to help me.

Comment: well for a start `id` attributes must be unique. second `src` attributes should contain a url not a filepath

Comment: @Steve you are not right about the filepath

Comment: Why should I use a URL instead of a filepath? Somthing about secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID should be unique in both HTML4 and HTML5.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html

> id = name [CS]
>     This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). [DOM]

You can modify your PHP and JavaScript code as following

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>OnClick</title>
</head>

<body>

<table id="imgTable">
    <tr><?php

$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(_FILE_)).'../up/to/my/folder');

$imgID = 0;

while($file = readdir($handle)){
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
        echo '        <td><img src="../up/to/my/folder/' .$file. '" alt="image" class="imgClass" id="imageId_'.$imgID.'"></td>\n';
        $imgID++;
    }
}
    ?></tr>
</table>

<div id="imgViewer">
    <img src="../up/to/my/folder/imgholder.png" id="bigImg">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// create array of all images inside "imgTable"
var imglist = document.getElementById("imgTable").getElementsByTagName("img");

// loop to create onclick event for each image
for(i=0; i<imglist.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(imglist[i].id).addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById('bigImg').src = this.src;
    });
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

code is tested and working...

You can run following snippet for demo (I replace images and manually add html code instead of php part)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>OnClick</title>
</head>

<body>

<table id="imgTable">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/99ACX4d.jpg" alt="image" class="imgClass" id="imageId_1"></td>
        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/lXVuaa3.jpg" alt="image" class="imgClass" id="imageId_2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="imgViewer">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QsYVnSd.png" id="bigImg">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

// create array of all images inside "imgTable"
var imglist = document.getElementById("imgTable").getElementsByTagName("img");

// loop to create onclick event for each image
for(i=0; i<imglist.length; i++) {
 document.getElementById(imglist[i].id).addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById('bigImg').src = this.src;
 });
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also format your code and use some code editor with autocomplete and debugger. You have many small mistakes (e.g. `<tr>` instead of `<td>` in php echo, you forgot dot (.) before src in JS, there is no **t** in getElemen**t**sByClassName).

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that. But still no reaction by Click on an image. I'll figured it out. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MaximilianFixl it's not working because event listener not working on getElementsByTagName and getElemensByClassName. They generating array of elements and you should loop to add event listener for each one. I modify my answer, test it and add working demo snippet. Just click "Run code snippet" under second snippet for demo.

Comment: I'll try that! Thank you! And addEventListener is only not working with getElementsByTagName and getElementsByClassName? Does it only work with getElementById? I'm thankful for that tip!

Comment: Yes it's working for getElementById because as I already mentioned ID should be unique and getElementById returns single element instead of array. Read my code and you will get the idea... I'm using getElementsByTagName to get array of img elements and using getElementById to add event listener for each element in this array.

Answer (score 1):

replace this line

```
document.getElementById('bigImg')src = img[i].src;
```

with

```
document.getElementById('bigImg').src = img[i].src;
```

you forgot . berfore src

and try this for click event

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img').addEventListener("click", function() {}
```

seems like your all images has same id so it will not apply on all images, id have to be unique
you can also do this in jquery for click

```
$('.imgClass').click(function(){

});
```

Comment: Of cause! unique ID´s. Ok I changed it. But still no reaction by click on the image. Not even the imgViewer is going to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

first give a same class name to all images(for example class name is test) and then

write below code

```
$('.test').on('click',function(){

   var src = $(this).attr('src');

   // here place your rest of the code


});
```